# Using Intraday data instead of Daily Exports for firebase events

Tags: events, google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

Context: our daily export has grown over 1 million rows of data a day and we don't have the budget to use GA360.

But as we noticed our historical data, intraday events covers about 98% of daily exports.

Has anyone used intraday events exclusively for their analytical purpose? Is it stable and trustworthy? We notice that if we turn off daily export on GA4, the intraday table won't stop and won't be deleted after 48-72hrs (normally it is deleted after the daily export table appears, but since we turned it off, it stays there).

Comment: please provide us an update, were you able to figure this out? So the documentation says: Standard GA4 properties have a BigQuery Export limit of 1 million events for Daily (batch) exports. There is no limit on the number of events for Streaming export. If your property consistently exceeds the export limit, the daily BigQuery export will be paused and previous days’ exports will not be reprocessed. Does this mean all I have to do to circumvent the 1 million event daily export limit is to switch from daily batch exports to streaming exports? This is too good to be true.